# Get the time in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have the following error :

```
IllegalArgumentException Parameter declaration .format should be
a vector  clojure.core/assert-valid-fdecl (core.clj:6732)
```

With this simple function :

```
(defn getNowDateString

    (.format(java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "ddMMyyyy:HHmmss")(java.util.Date.)))
)
```

Edit :

In the REPL

```
 => (.format(java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "ddMMyyyy:HHmmss")(java.util.Date.)))
 "23072013:094839"
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to switch from `java.util.Date` to [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time), it's the best datetime solution for clojure:

```
(unparse (formatter "ddMMyyyy:HHmmss") (now))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I forgot vector for function params.

```
(defn getNowDateString []

    (.format(java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "ddMMyyyy:HHmmss")(java.util.Date.)))
)
```

Thank you !